# null with cast vs Unchecked.defaultof?

Tags: f#

I have come across two ways to create a properly typed `null` value in F#:

```
// null with cast
let mutable x = null :> MyReferenceType

// Unchecked.defaultof
let mutable x = Unchecked.defaultof<MyReferenceType>
```

Is there any reason to favour one over the other?

Comment: In F#, it is recommended to avoid using `null` and instead use the `Option<'a>` type. That is of course off-question, but worth mentioning.

Comment: @MalteR of course, but sometimes you need to interact with C#

Comment: I assume you want  to use this with C# reference types, as the doc states `This function is unsafe in the sense that some F# values do not have proper null values`. Have you tried looking at the IL to see if there is any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference, sometimes there is just more than one way to do things. But usually Unchecked.defaultof() is used in a generic context where you don't know the type ahead of time and so you don't know the default. You certainly know that the default for MyReferenceType is null. So I would go with the first declaration. And actually, even that is a tad ugly, with the cast. Most folks would probably just write that as

```
let x : MyReferenceType = null
```

Comment: I should clarify, by "no difference" I just meant you get null in both cases. Using  Unchecked.defaultof() is of course slower, as it does work at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`Unchecked.defaultof` is not an expression, so you can use with `nameof` operator.

```
let nnn = nameof (null :> ILogger).BeginScope // Error: Expression does not have a name.

let yyy = nameof Unchecked.defaultof<ILogger>.BeginScope
```